# Check if array of objects contains key equals to string

Tags: angularjs

This is angularjs app.
In a view I have access to an array of objects:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{"name":"blue"},{"name":"red"}];
```

I have then a `div` that should display only if the `arrayOfObjects` contains an entry with

```
name=='red'
```

I had a look at "`contains`" but seems to work only on arrays of elements, not of objects.
Is it possibile to do this directly in the view without needing to code this in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the array does not understand what is inside of it (in this case object), you have to check each element in the condition.

A short-way to do that, would be using the `some` method like this:

```
<div *ngIf="arrayOfObjects.some(({ name }) => name == 'red')"></div>
```

The `some` will return true if some element in arrayOfObjects satisfy this condition. Other way, would be to map the `arrayOfObjetcs` to `arrayOfNames` and them check if that array contains name, like this:
`arrayOfObjects.map(({ name }) => name).contains('red')`